# Syntax error, unexpected '[' when loading Facebook SDK into CakePHP Project

Tags: facebook, cakephp

So I am doing the very basic installation of the Facebook SDK into my cakephp project. I've added it into the `Vendor/` folder.

In my `bootstrap.php` file I've added this line of code:

`require_once APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-master' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'Facebook' . DS . 'facebook.php';`

When I load the application afterwards I get the following error:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected '[' 
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\app\Vendor\facebook-php-sdk-v4-master\src\Facebook\Facebook.php  
Line: 125
```

I've re-downloaded the sdk files to ensure I have them all. Any idea why I would be getting this?

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: Whatever is included CakePHP 2.7x. Sorry I am a bit new to CakePHP Development, so not sure the proper way to check.

Comment: I may actually be using CakePhp 2.6.x version on this project.

Comment: PHP is provided by your ampps stack, and it might be outdated. Please show the output of `php -v` in a `CMD` window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like PHP is not recognizing the syntax used.

[Line 125](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/5.1.2/src/Facebook/Facebook.php#L125) of `\src\Facebook\Facebook.php` contains:

```
public function __construct(array $config = [])
```

`$config` defaults to an empty array, expressed in short array syntax. [Short arrays where introduced in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

Make sure you are using PHP version 5.4 or higher.

Comment: It looks like I was using CakePHP version 5.3 in my AMPPS stack. I changed it to 5.6 and it now works. Any idea why then, afterwards when I attempt

`$this->Facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     =>  'ID',
        'secret'    =>  'secret',
        ));`
That I get an error Class 'Facebook' not found in App